# wxPython GetBackgroundColour() function on linux and windows platforms

Tags: windows, wxpython, ubuntu-16.04

I have asked a [similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857735/wx-python-how-to-create-an-image-with-colour-of-the-panel-background) but unfortunately no one was able to help me.

I want to create an image in a wxPython application with the colour of the panel background. The problem is, that on linux, the wxPython function

```
self.GetBackgroundColour()
```

does not return the true colour  of the background (see the image below)

[image]

whereas on Windows it seems to be ok

[image]

I have tried various (unsatisfactory) workarounds, but now that I am testing the application on multiple platforms it is adding yet another platform specific coding requirement.

Am I being too precious about this? Or is it something that I should expect to work out of the box?

The code used to generate these images follows (any image can be used in place of 'any.png'):

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Image')
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        static_bitmap_A = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap('any.png')
        static_bitmap_A.SetBitmap(bitmap)
        sizer.Add(static_bitmap_A, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        image = wx.Image('any.png')
        colour = self.GetBackgroundColour()
        red, green, blue = colour[0], colour[1], colour[2]
        #red, green, blue = 0, 0, 0
        for row in range(image.GetSize()[0]):
            for column in range(image.GetSize()[1]):
                image.SetRGB(row, column, red, green, blue)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap(image)
        static_bitmap_B = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        static_bitmap_B.SetBitmap(bitmap)
        sizer.Add(static_bitmap_B, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That *"similar"* question is the same question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I agree that the problem is the same. I have supplied new information by showing the difference between windows and linux and I could bot do that effectively in a comment. As no answer was made before, this new aspect may prompt a constructive reply.

Comment: Instead of asking the same question again, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50857735/edit) your previous question.